# Change Color by Group with visreg and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, visreg

After running a logistic regression with a binary predictor, when I try to plot the results using visreg and ggplot the legend indicates that the colors have been changed by group but they don't change in the graph.

Here is an illustration of the problem using the mtcars data.

```
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars, 10)
```

The only two binary variables are the vs and am, but they need to be converted from numeric the factor for this illustration to work.

```
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
```

Run the model.

```
logit1 <- glm(vs ~ am, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")
```

Now try to plot the results using visreg as well as additional ggplot functions to customize the colors and labels.

```
visreg(logit1, "am", scale = "response", gg = TRUE, rug = FALSE, by = "am", overlay=TRUE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#1b9e77", "#d95f02"), 
                     breaks=c(0, 1), 
                     labels=c("Zeros", "Ones"))
```

I would for both the line and the shaded area should be orange (#d95f02) for the am = 1 group and both the line and the shaded area to be green (#1b9e77) for the am = 0 group.  As you can see, that is not what the code produces. [image]

Comment: One option might be to use ggplot_build(), which will let you pull out the raw summary data from the regression. That file will be easier to manipulate than the visreg object.

Comment: @cardinal40 Oof! I can see how ggplot_build potentially adds a lot of flexibility, but it looks like I would have to build the entire graph from scratch using this. I'm not finding a whole lot of examples or materials on it's use.  Are you familiar with it enough to quickly and easily apply it to the example I provided?  I'm also looking for a long term solution to this problem and [here](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/11/20/under-the-hood-of-ggplot2-graphics-in-r/) they state that Hadley Wickham has warned against relying on ggplot_build too heavily as it will likely deprecate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no functionality in `visreg` to enable you to do something like this right now.  You can certainly change colors with, for example:

```r
visreg(logit1, "am", scale = "response", gg = TRUE, rug = FALSE, by = "am", overlay=TRUE,
       fill.par=list(fill="#1b9e77"), line.par=list(col='#d95f02'))
```

But what you're describing is constructing an entirely different plot: one in which values of `am` are mapped to different colors.  This would involve a completely different `aes` object that the plot is built upon.  Unless there's some amazing `ggplot2` trick out there that I am not aware of, there is no way to do this without rebuilding the plot from scratch.